# Weird normals(I already Recalculate Normals,Remove doubles)

Tags: modeling, normals

So I am having a problem with my mesh I am not positive if it is normals I am a bit of a noob to blender probably been using it for 2 months  and I don't know something you may know
any help will be appreciated this is how it looks like
https://i.gyazo.com/21b0692adb4aafb5e089992e9361a344.mp4
ask any questions
and as I said
I already remove doubles and recalculated normals
Here is the file
[image]
Fixed

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell from the clip, any chance you could upload your .blend file? You can do it here - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Yes give me one second

Comment: I have added the blend file

Comment: Hey. I think you uploaded your .blend1 instead of your .blend. Do you mind re-uploading? The file cannot be opened otherwise.

Comment: Sorry one second

Comment: Okay I done it it should work now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, there are a couple of problems here.

The first and foremost is that you have many edges marked "sharp".

[image: Sharp1]

To fix this, simply enter edit mode, select the whole mesh (<kbd>A</kbd>), right-click and select "clear sharp"

[image: Sharp2]

However, as you can see, the mesh is still affected because of "ugly" topology. Blender favors the use of Quad based topology, and though sometimes tri's or n-gons are unavoidable, they are best kept on flat (non curved) surfaces. To reduce the chance of shading based artifacts, always try to keep your mesh as quad-based as possible.

[image: Sharp3]

To fix this for your project, you can either re-topologize it manually, or an easier approach would be to use a **Remesh Modifier**, either in it's own, or in conjunction with manual adjustments.

[image: Remesh]

Once this is done, if you want your mesh "smooth" again, you could add a Subdivision Surface Modifier, and shade smooth. (NOTE - the smooth shading did not work properly for me until I applied the Remesh Modifier. I am currently using 2.9, so I'm not sure if it's unique to this version, but if it isn't shading smooth for you, try applying the modifier first)

[image: Smooth]

Comment: Aw man thank you so much this been a problem for the longest I'm pretty sure a bunch of other people will use this post in the future will use this as well!

Comment: Hey, no problem. The remesh modifier might not give the exact topology you want, but it should at least make it easier to adjust manually if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I had strange-looking shapes that went back to typical appearance after I enter *Edit Mode*, select shapes and go to the menu *Mesh > Normals > Reset Vectors*